# Why the 3rd li element is always focused when load the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, html-lists

I'm creating a simple site that has menu and a submenu. When the page is loaded, it's showing Re-Board and its submenu just like it has been hovered from nowhere. I want the Home `li` to be the default menu when the page is loaded. What's the problem? I have checked my css and js files and done some testing but the problem stills exist. Please help. Many thanks !!!

The HTML structure is like this.

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li style=""><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Company</a>
        <span>
            <a href="">The Company</a> |
            <a href="">The Team</a> |
            <a href="">Careers</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Re-Board</a>
        <span>
            <a href="">What We Do</a> |
            <a href="">Our Process</a> |
            <a href="">Testimonials</a>
            </span>
            </li>
    <li><a href="">Design Database</a></li>
    <li><a href="">New</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Catalog</a></li>
    <li class="none-b"><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

My full code :)

http://jsfiddle.net/X9DwY/

Comment: We need to see the associated CSS before being able to help you.

Comment: Please also post your CSS code.

Comment: You mentioned that you checked your CSS and JS code, but didn't include either. :/

Comment: I recommend to create a fiddle so people will be able to help you out. (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Okay I will post jsfiddle in a minute.

Comment: Why (if I may ask) are you using Javascript for this when the entire thing can be done in CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/X9DwY/2/

Comment: I don't know. It just follow the order. It is not my site actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to hide the second sub menu if you do not want it to display right away:

```
<span style="display:none;"></span>
```

instead of:

```
<span></span>
```

Comment: but how can I set Home menu to be default hovered when load the page.

Comment: You could also hide the first `<span>` if you don't want any sub menus to be displayed by default. Is that what you're thinking?

Comment: Yes. I already hide all the span. But again,  how can I set Home menu to be default hovered when load the page.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do. The home menu does not have a sub menu in your example.